# How do I programmatically create a list control?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

How do I programmatically create a list control?

ie:

```
CListCtrl *lstCtrl = new CListCtrl;
lstCtrl->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(10, 10, 320, 280), this, 0x285);
```

But how do you set this up with data, column sizes, and headers, lines, etc... 
All examples I find show how to do all this using the wizard and using its variables it creates in its code.

Comment: Do explain what framework etc. this is about. Add the proper tag(s).

Comment: Read the MSDN documentation for the actual class. All functions and variables, and how to use them without a wizard, should be there.

Comment: Next time, please add also a tag for the framework you're using. C++ and VisualC++ means also QT framework, wxWidgets etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want it in ReportMode: use `LVS_REPORT` flag in the `Create` call.

Then you can call `InsertColumn` to add columns and `InsertItem` to add items. Then, use `SetItemText` to set the text of additional columns in an already inserted item.